# Create dynamic sitemap from URL with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, sitemap, web-crawler

I am currently working on an application where I scrape information from a number of different sites. To get the deeplink for the desired topic on a site I rely on the sitemap that is provided (e.g. "Forum"). As I am expanding I came across some sites that don't provide a sitemap themselves, so I was wondering if there was any way to generate it within Rails from the top level domain?

I am using Nokogiri and Mechanize to retrieve data, so if there is any functionality that could help to tackle that task it would be easier to integrate.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Spidering sites is rarely a generic task as sites are usually custom-made. Generic spiders return a high amount of garbage that requires filtering. Writing a spider isn't that hard, and there are many tutorials and pages describing the various aspects of doing so. There are many pages, including Ruby-related ones here on SO for this too, so I suggest you search more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [Spidr gem](https://github.com/postmodern/spidr) like so:

```
url_map = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = [] }

Spidr.site('http://intranet.com/') do |spider|
  spider.every_link do |origin,dest|
    url_map[dest] << origin
  end
end
```